# Looking for interesting math functions that alternate between multiple different trigonometric parameters

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking for functions that do something like

f(x) = { log(x) , if x is a multiple of 3;
sin(x) , if x is not a multiple of 3
}

But not being super random like the above (preferrably somewhat continuous). The example conditions above can be modified to x/0.001 is a multiple of 3 or 4 or anything of that sort. The idea is to do a stress test for GPU thread divergence while also being useful in some way.

Comment: What does "somewhat continuous" mean here? $\log x$ is unbounded and $\sin x$ is bounded so the two eventually grow arbitrarily far apart.

Comment: You might have to ask the question on a different stack exchange website if you're looking for a way to stress-test your GPU. Most of us aren't familiar with computers.

Comment: You cannot have "continuous" and "alternate between multiple parameters" if the alternation is based on "point-width" changes as in your example. You can define functions on *intervals* and have continuity, if you take care that the piecewise functions agree at the stitches. But when the piecewise functions are continuous and you jump to another value for a single point, then jump back, the only way for the result to be continuous is for that "other" value to be what the surrounding piecewise function would have been anyway.